# python 3.x for loop not stopping at desired value

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

i'm reading a beginners book written in Python 2.x but I decided to follow it using 3.5

the book is about data wrangling and while reading an Excel file using the library `xlrd` it gives a quick example of how `Counters` work:

```
count = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if count < 10;
        print i
    count += 1
print 'Count: ', count
```

first of all, i know in Python 3.x `print` is actually `print()` and i also learned that in 2.x `range(1000)` IS NOT the same in 3.x

so i managed to run the code without errors but not with the desired result:

```
count = 0
my_list = list(range(1000))
for i in my_list:
    if count < 50:
        print(i)
    count += 1
print(count)
```

the result were the numbers from 1001 to 2000. clearly not what i meant it to do, so it made my think if the `+=` was the same for 3.x but couldnt find much information, so i tried the (at least to me) logical way:

```
count = 0
my_list = list(range(1000))
for i in my_list:
    if count < 50:
        print(i)
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

but now the result are all numbers from 0 to 1000 BUT all numbers from 1 to 49 are repeated once. so i changed `count` for just `i` but made no difference.

clearly none of my attempts stopped at 50...

i appreciate all input in advance

Comment: I don't really understand this question. The first two code blocks will output exactly the same numbers (0-9 from the `print` calls in the loop, then `1000` at the end, since you're counting all the values, not just the ones you're printing). I don't see how you'd get numbers higher than 1000 without using a different `range` (or running the loop several times without resetting `count`).

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is originating from increment-ing count at the end of your for loop.

the way you have it written if you do for k in range(5) ... counter will increment from 0 all the way up to 5, because it increments once past it's value on each iteration.

Running this code will sow that count counts higher than your itterating variable k in the loop.
print ("Hello World!");

```
count = 0 
for k in range(5):
    print("k: "+str(k))
    print("count: "+str(count))
    count+=1
    print("countNow: "+str(count))
```